# R shiny: Tooltip on scatter plot when selecting item from selectizeInput

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, tooltip, selectinput

I am editing this question to make it a little bit clearer.

I am new to Shiny. I have the MWE below, adapted slightly from https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/16220 and using `mtcars` data.

It works as intended to show a tooltip for each point in the scatter plot when hovering over it.

But I would like an additional feature here. I have a `selectizeInput` list with all the car models (one per point in the scatter plot). I would like that the same tooltip that appears when hovering over the point, appears as well when selecting the car model from the list.

So not only have a point tooltip appear upon hovering over it, but also upon selection of the "point ID" (the car model) in the `selectizeInput` list.

Please check my MWE below. The tooltip shows when hovering, but it does not show when selecting in the `selectizeInput` list yet. Not sure how to pass this info. Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Tooltips in ggplot2 + shiny"),

  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput(outputId = "car_models"),
    width = 3
  ),

  mainPanel(
    # this is an extra div used ONLY to create positioned ancestor for tooltip
    # we don't change its position
    div(
      style = "position:relative",
      plotOutput("scatterplot",
                 hover = hoverOpts("plot_hover", delay = 100, delayType = "debounce")),
      uiOutput("hover_info", style = "pointer-events: none")
    ),
    width = 7
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
      geom_point()
  })

  output$car_models <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput(inputId = "car_models", label = "Car models:",
                   choices = rownames(mtcars),
                   selected = NULL,
                   multiple = TRUE)
  })

  output$hover_info <- renderUI({
    hover <- input$plot_hover
    
    hover_function(mtcars, hover)
  })
}


hover_function <- function(mtcars, hover){
    point <- nearPoints(mtcars, hover, threshold = 5, maxpoints = 1, addDist = TRUE)
    if (nrow(point) == 0) return(NULL)
    
    left_px <- hover$coords_css$x
    top_px <- hover$coords_css$y
    
    # create style property for tooltip
    # background color is set so tooltip is a bit transparent
    # z-index is set so we are sure tooltip will be on top
    style <- paste0("position:absolute; z-index:100; background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.85); ",
                    "left:", left_px + 2, "px; top:", top_px + 2, "px;")
    
    # actual tooltip created as wellPanel
    wellPanel(
      style = style,
      p(HTML(paste0("<b> Car: </b>", rownames(point), "<br/>",
                    "<b> mpg: </b>", point$mpg, "<br/>",
                    "<b> hp: </b>", point$hp, "<br/>",
                    "<b> Distance from left: </b>", left_px, "<b>, from top: </b>", top_px)))
    )
}


runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image: test]

Comment: Where do you want your dropdown to be? What do you want to use it for? What do you mean "the same tooltip that appears when hovering over the points"?

Comment: The idea is to have a drop down list with the car models on the left sidebarPanel. When selecting a car model in the list, a tooltip should appear in the scatter plot, in the same way as it appears when hovering over the point the corresponds to that car model.

Comment: So not only have a point tooltip appear upon hovering over it, but also upon selection of the "point ID" in a selectizeInput list.

Comment: Not a good way I would consider. So when and how does the tooltip triggered by the dropdown disappear? This seems complicated, I would suggest you use `plotly` which has all your required features built-in, no need of these complex tricks.

Comment: the tooltip will appear when selecting the car model in the list, and disappear when deselecting it. Is that possible? As far as I know, plotly does not offer this feature...

Comment: plotly leaves the group you selected and hides all other groups. Then you can hover on the points left on the plot. These points only belong to the group you selected.